# Cryptosytem Question

Tags: cryptography, hash, md5

A file is encrypted and placed on a secure FTP server. An MD5 hash is taken of the file and also placed on the FTP server. A userlogs in to the server and downloads both files, however, the hash fails to match the archive. In this case, what basic goal of a cryptosystem has failed?

I have been trying to answer this question. Would anybody be able to hint me out on this? i've tried numerous Google searches.

Comment: There are a few things that could have been an issue. There could have possibly been an error during the hashing (of either you or the original uploader). There could have also been a corruption error during the download process.

Comment: What was the goal of the cryptosystem to *begin with*? This looks like a success, not a failure, to me.

Comment: Sounds like some homework question to me, while also lacking important details: What is a "secure" FTP server; ist it to be defined here? Is the MD5 computed *before* transferring on the FTP server, and was it verified before transferring file and hash to the FTP server? If the question was about the "security features" *disclosure*, *damage*, or *deletion*, then the answer would be (most likely): *Damage*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a flawed system if its meant to ensure data wasn't tampered by a malicious attacker.

Any attacker who can tamper with the transmission of the file (or the file on the FTP site), could have similarly tampered with the transmission of the md5sum (or the storage of the md5sum on the site) and changed it to something that corresponds to the tampered value.  So the scheme even at its best provides little security.  At best it provides an assurance that the file was fully downloaded.

Really you need to establish trust in transmitting the md5.

Granted if you got the md5 from a trusted source (e.g., downloaded over HTTPS from trusted site and assume that HTTPS isn't broken; that site didn't maliciously alter it) than yes this could indicate the data wasn't tampered with.  (While md5 suffers collision attacks -- its possible to construct two different files (modifying both) such that md5(f1) = md5(f2), no published attack has shown md5 is vulnerable to preimage attacks -- if I have an arbitrary hash h1, generate some file that will have that hash.)

Answer (score 2):

There are a lot of ways to look at security questions, and rarely a "right" answer.

In this case, you might want to start by listing out what the basic goal(s) of the cryptosystem is/are; i.e., "what's the point?". From there, you can consider what is not being fulfilled if the hash doesn't match.

In this case, you're looking at a system that works by posting a hash along with the content. Why might this be desirable? What guarantees/claims are you *no longer* able to make if the hash doesn't match the content?

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

This because the hash computed is of the original file, and not the encrypted file. How ever, if the individual downloads the encrypted file and calculates the hash, it will not match because the first hash value will be of the original file, not the encrypted file